# How to cut a complex shape into a curved surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

This is a torch 1948 Olympic relay torch. I'm stuck on the part where the olimplc rings are cut in the side of the torch. I have the overall shape of the torch, just not the rings on the side of the torch.
I'm modeling this for 3D printing.

I need help to make the cuts and place the rings exactly on the curve of the torch. They have to keep the overall shape of the rings, but match the torch.

I'm looking for a clear and quick solution. I can give you my blender file if that helps, and as many references as you need.
[image: Olympic torch reference image]

Comment: In this kind of case, you should indicate what you have concretely done so far. You said "many methods", but what are they and which problems did you encounter ? That will help your question to be well received...

Comment: Yes you have right about your notes. So, this model is for 3D printing. And I start with a cylinder to make the shape, and then I try to make the circles to fit on it with the shrinkwrap modifier. But is lot of working. And futher more,when I try to make the holes by any kind it's result in non uniforme resulting.  I try to del the between faces And then to make new points (vertics) by cntr+LMB but this makes vertics freely in the space. What I 'm asking is what stradegy is better, cutting holes with boolean or knife, or try to scylpting? Just a stradegy. Thanks

Comment: You think too complicated. AFAIK no 3d printer delivers a smooth and detailed model that won't be needing sanding or any other kinds of reworks. Don't bother with the cutouts and also don't bother with a continuous mesh. Model the details by using the described methods on https://www.sculpteo.com/de/tutorial-de/bereiten-sie-ihr-modell-fuer-den-3d-druck-mit-blender/ and do the cutouts between the rings on the printed model. Oh, and also use latices instead of shrinkwrap for the curved surfaces.

Comment: To  "metaphor_set": Thank you, I think you gave me an idea. I try to make it in a simple plane and then connect 4 same and try to make a cylinder (any idea how to do?) and then an overal shape with the Lattice. I will tell you if that's working. (I have read the sculpteo already, but thanks anyway). About printers you have wrong, I have print more detailing things than that.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In complement to the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61123/how-to-cut-a-complex-shape-into-a-curved-surface/61278#61278) given by [Patdog](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/26911/patdog) (which stay the good answer corresponding to the exact question), you can also work on the ring on a flat surface and make the torch shape after, as it is easier to use the boolean modifier or other technics to make the rings when flat.

Here a stack of modifiers, starting from two flat shapes (the ring part and a slice to complement the torch) :

- The slice is repeated using an array modifier and the ring part as '*start cap*'
- The curve gives the vertical shape for the torch
- The simple deform makes the circular shape of the torch

The vertices on the border of the rings part and these on the border of the slice part need to correspond (same amount, same position)

You'll need to adjust a bit the two base objects positions relatively to their centers in order to have a good junction with the array modifier (so make sure to work with rounded measures in cm for instance).

The amount of repetitions given by the '*count*' of the array modifier will lead the torch diameter.

The curve (used in the curve modifier) shape can be adjusted on top of the stack so that you can see immediately the result on the rounded torch.

[image]

Once you have adjusted all as you want, you'll need to apply the modifiers and remove doubles to complete the junction of the simple deform bending.

The bottom part of the torch (with the texts) can be done the same way : a bent flat surface.

In both cases, just make sure to have the good/enough inner geometry so that the bending can be done smoothly.

Comment: To Lemon: Just see your answer too. What can I say, a thank you it's the less I have to say. I'm shocked with your detailing answer. Best of the best. This blog is far away the best of the world!!!

Answer (score 10):

3 Basic shapes need to be modeled: The relief rings (yellow), their background rings (orange) and a cutter (red). These can be created from duplicated circles that are joined into one set.[image] The important thing is that all three elements share the same origin - that way they move in tandem with the modifier curve. The same modifier must be added to each element.[image]

A Boolean difference is used to subtract the red cutter from the main object. The back ground rings (orange) will replace the void left by the cutter [image][image]. All that's left is to select the islands formed with the <kbd>L</kbd> key and delete them.

The remaining elements can then be joined to the main object...[image: curve modifier][image]

If you model each part cleaning they should be easy to print.

Comment: Very nice result, I have UV this answer because of that, but you should detail a bit more because it seems to be difficult to follow the "how to" here (we only see results in the screen shots).

Comment: Had intended to show an approach...not necessarily a step by step tutorial. Updated with some more details and hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: To Patdog: Thank you, thank you, thank you. This answer is the far awy the best that I was expecting. What can I say. You're master. You save my day. If you came ever in Athens hope to buy you a drink.